# How to install allure in MAC manually

Tags: allure

I am trying to install allure in MAC not able to it.
I am getting the error "-bash: allure: command not found".

I have downloaded allure-commandline-2.9.0.tgz and allure-commandline-2.9.0.zip from the below link: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.9.0/

I tried with both but it is not working.
Steps I have followed:
download the .tgz or .zip file.
unzip/untar the file.
set /allure-2.9.0/bin dir to the PATH variable.
Restart the terminal.
trying to run allure --version command.

But I am getting the error "-bash: allure: command not found".

Comment: echo your full PATH and show us. To do so, type  "echo $PATH" in your terminal. I guess your install folder is not /allure-2.9.0/bin (<- root dir)

Comment: I didn't install directly. I am trying to install manually.

Comment: yes, you unpacked a tar-ball. The quastion is: where you did that? And: Is your PATH environment correctly set?

Comment: I created a separate folder and added the path to the PATH variable just like we do in windows. yes The PATH environment variable is set correctly.

Comment: If the call "allure --version" does not work, the PATH environment is not set correctly. Give more information. In which folder did you unpack the tool. Which path instruction have you added to the PATH env.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation folder of the tool is not /allure-2.9.0/bin

A good practise is to create a "bin" folder inside your user-account: "~/bin" and include this to the $PATH environment. From now on you can link or copy your extracted tool from e.g. ~/Downloads/allure-2.9.0/bin to ~/bin

You don't have to extend the PATH variable for each new tool.